# Не могу скрыть объекты на Яндекс.Карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Прошу помощи в решении такой задачи. Читаю файл формата geojson экпортированный из Яндекс.Карт. Если тип объекта "Point" я его кластеризирую и соответственно добавляю в массив myGeoObjects для последующего вывода. Так как в объекте geoJSON этот элемент выводить не надо, я устанавливаю свойство visible для него в false, но оно не срабатывает. И у меня выводится на экран и точка из geoJSON и из myGeoObjects. Как мне отключить вывод некоторых объектов из geoJSON? И еще небольшой вопрос - почему не работает установка цвета иконки в кластере?

```
ymaps.ready(function () {

    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [, ],
            zoom: 8,
            controls: ['zoomControl']
        }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
    map.controls.get('zoomControl').options.set({size: 'auto'});
    // Инициализируем массив объектов для будущего кластера
    myGeoObjects = [];
    var i = 0;
    // Загружаем GeoJSON файл, экспортированный из Конструктора карт.
    jQuery.getJSON('')
        .done(function (geoJson) {

            geoJson.features.forEach(function (obj) {
                // Задаём контент балуна
                obj.properties.balloonContent = obj.properties.description;
                // Находим полигоны и задаем их свойства
                if (obj.geometry.type == "Polygon") { 
                }
                // Находим линии и задаем их свойства
                else if (obj.geometry.type == "LineString") { 
                }
                // Находим точки и добавляем их в myGeoObjects
                else if (obj.geometry.type == "Point") {
                    obj.options = {visible: false}; // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
                    // Добавляем объект в массив кластера
                    myGeoObjects[i] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                    geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [obj.geometry.coordinates[0], obj.geometry.coordinates[1]] },
                    options: {preset: "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"} // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, цвет точки не меняется
                });
                i = i+1;
                };
            });
            // Добавляем описание объектов в формате JSON в менеджер объектов.
            objectManager.add(geoJson);
            // Добавляем объекты на карту.
            map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
            // Работаем с кластером и выводим
            var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer();
            clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
            map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
        });
});
```

Comment: А почему не использовать кластеризацию, встроенную в objectManager? Какова цель такого разделения? Ну и строго говоря objectManager нигде не обещает возможность отключения видимости объектов вроде как. Ненужные объекты следует из него удалять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лишние элементы нужно удалять из менеджера объектов, а не скрывать недокументированными для него параметрами, тем более, что вам эти дубликаты не нужны.
Можно выкидывать лишнее в цикле перебора объектов.

А опции (цвет меток) следует задавать без **options:** и после описания геометрии, а не внутри:

```
myGeoObjects[i] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [geoJson.features[j].geometry.coordinates[0], geoJson.features[j].geometry.coordinates[1]]}},
                {preset: "islands#darkGreenCircleIcon"} // так работает
             );
```

Пример, демонстрирующий работу на произвольных данных: https://jsfiddle.net/6tzj5bxc/